# Max-height and max-width not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display different sized image in my home page. i am using max-width and max-height but images are not decorating correctly. i am using bootsrap. Here is my php code:

```
<? while($chanelrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="<?=$chanelrow['chanel_logo']?>" style="max-width:200; max-height:200" alt="">
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3>Project Two</h3>
                <h4>Subheading</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Ut, odit velit cumque vero doloremque repellendus distinctio
                maiores rem expedita a nam vitae modi quidem similique ducimus!
                Velit, esse totam tempore.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">View Project <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

[image: This is the output]

How to handle my images size?

Comment: older IE doesn't recognize max-width and max-height, but mainly you need to add "px" to your values (200px)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the unit type (px, %, em etc) to the width/height number:

```
<img class="img-rounded" src="<?=$chanelrow['chanel_logo']?>" style="max-width:200px; max-height:200px" alt="">
```